# Two column layout in Wordpress?

Tags: themes, screen-layout

I'm not sure if this is a general web design or Wordpress question.

I have a simple demo here to illustrate my question.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/wp/

It's just a simple 2 column responsive layout.

My simple question is how do I spilt the content between the two columns.

The page will be a page in Wordpress and not posts (I think).

I wanted to create a page in Wordpress and place the text on the content area

There is one content area in Wordpress, is there a way to split this content
so I can say this is the left column, this is the right column.

The text will all be on the same subject but I need to split it between two columns.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This question would be best answered as a purely HTML/CSS question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a WordPress question but my first plugin solution is a "WordPress" way to do it. My other solutions are more general web design. I'm also making the assumption that you have some experience with custom templates/scripts.

If you want to manually do it you can use something like [Grid Columns](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/grid-columns/) This is good if the content isn't going to be dynamic and you can just set it once in the admin interface and then forget it.

If it's dynamic content and you're okay with using JavaScript you can use [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

You can also [split using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259689/split-a-text-into-two-columns-with-php) but here things get a bit tricker.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you look here - 6 Ways to Display WordPress Post Content in Multiple Columns - http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/.

Comment: Please add relevant content/code to your answer, rather than merely including a link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question looking at the code you just create a new page and you can paste this in

```
 <section>
  <div id="leftCol" class="col">
    <p> Your content here</p>
  </div> 
  <div id="rightCol" class="col">
    <p> Your content here</p>

  </div> 
</section>
```

It should create the columns for you and you just need to swap out the content.